# Use a string from app settings in a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, web-config, sql-server-2012

Objective: use a string from app settings within a query

Code:

```
private SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection();
private String[] strSomeValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeValue"].ToString().Split(';');

String strSQL = Type.SelectedValue;
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnection.CreateCommand();

if (strSQL == "SomeValue")
 {
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Value 
                        FROM Types
                        WHERE "Some Value"
  }
```

The idea is to have the Some Value portion of the query be filled with the string from app settings. Thank you in advance for any references, comments and suggestions

Comment: An example of `SomeValue` ?

Comment: Are you trying to add just a value, or an entire SQL clause?  The two are *very* different.  A value can just be added as a query parameter, but the clause would mean that you're treating the value as *executable code* which is a whole lot more dangerous.

Comment: `<add key="SomeValue" value="'1=1' GO DROP TABLE Types GO --" />`

Comment: @Jonesy right point, but no GO just `); DROP....--`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx):

```
const string query =
      "SELECT Value"
    + "FROM Types"
    + "WHERE Value = @SomeValue";

using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeValue", strSomeValue[0]);
    // TODO: open connection, execute command, get result
}
```